# How can I colour Write-Debug and Write-Verbose a specific colour in VS Code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have a simple aim here but the execution seems relatively complex. All I would like to do is format `Write-Debug` and `Write-Verbose` anywhere they appear as the first text in a line (sometimes indented but no characters in front of them).

I would like to format them the same colour as my comments (or just manually setting them to the same colour is fine). Potentially I might want the same formatting for the rest of the line but that is optional.

I have done a quick google but the depth on the answers seems a lot to get my head around for something so simple, hoping somebody can help simplify it!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "the answers seems a lot to get my head around for something so simple" - can you link to one or two of these answers? Perhaps someone here can help you digest them :)

Comment: I figure its just getting the tokenization to be a comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide. But going about that looks rather complicated and I can't find a simple guide, lots talk about changing the colour of a specific token, but in this case the token itself needs changing (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [Highlight extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight).

In your settings:

```
"highlight.regexes": {
  "((^\\s*Write-Debug)|(Write-Verbose))": { // A regex will be created from this string, don't forget to double escape it
    "regexFlags": "gm", // Flags used when building this regex
    "filterLanguageRegex": "powershell", // Apply only if current file's language matches this regex. Requires double escaping
    "decorations": [ // Decoration options to apply to the capturing groups
      { "color": "red" }, // Decoration options to apply to the first capturing group, in this case "//TODO"
    ]
  }
}
```

There are a lot more styling options at [decoration options](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DecorationRenderOptions).

[image: highlight powershell syntax]

---

To highlight the whole line use:

`"((^\\s*Write-Debug.*)|(Write-Verbose.*))": {`

the text has to be in a capture group to be decorated.  You could put the rest of the line into a different capture group if you wanted to decorate it differently.

Comment: Thanks, great and complete answer! I'm looking at it and thinking highlighting the whole line is probably a good idea but the regex that works on regexr.com doesn't work. I'm trying ```((^\\s*Write-Debug)|(Write-Verbose)).*```, any further awesome help appreciated!

Comment: I edited the answer to include the rest of the line in the same capture group.  Or you could make it a separate capture group with its own decorations too.